# What's the best method to use when creating a new SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql

I've always been creating new SqlCommands with command text and a connection  parameter, but I've also seen a number of people using a different method.

I always do this:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("text", SqlConnection);
```

but I've seen people do this:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = SqlConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "text";
```

which seems like an unnecessary extra line to me.

Is there any performance benefit to one method, or is the difference purely stylistic?

Comment: Makes no difference at all. What kind of difference did you imagine it would make? What you need to worry about is the missing `using` block.

Comment: primarily opinion-based

Comment: I wondered if maybe it's somehow safer/better practice with the second method, because most of the code that I'm maintaining right now does it that way.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder what universe I'm living in. I've been creating `SqlCommand`s for over 15 years and never noticed that `SqlConnection.CreateCommand()` even existed. Perhaps that's because I've never used `IDbCommand`.